# Which aircraft did I photograph at ZRH?

Tags: airliner, commercial-aviation, aircraft-identification

I took a couple of pictures of various aircraft and I would like to know which aircraft I photographed. I have no idea, expect that all of them took off from [ZRH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrich_Airport) and should be commercial airliners:

[image: Pegasus aircraft above runway on takeoff]

[image: Swiss aircraft on approach to land]

[image: Swiss aircraft on approach to land]

[image: Swiss aircraft on approach to land]

[image: Turkish aircraft on approach to land]

[image: Star Alliance aircraft on approach to land]

Comment: Beautiful pictures :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the plural of "aircraft" is "aircraft". :)

Comment: If you can read the immatriculation (at the rear of the aircraft), you may searh on [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/search/photo.search?regsearch=HB-IJF&distinct_entry=true)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the simplest things you can do is to **type in the registration into Google which will normally give you results of the type and history of the aircraft**.

Otherwise, many airlines don't operate too many types of aircraft so a **quick look on Wikipedia and looking through 'fleet'** should show you which types it may be, from which elimination should be pretty quick.

*The registration is normally visible on the back of the fuselage and under the wing (D-ABEP on the rear fuselage below), and the last two letters are (often) printed on the aircraft 'forehead' above the cockpit windows, the top of the tail and the nose gear doors (EP on the nose gear doors below).*

[image: Lufthansa]

---

Aircraft from your photos:

- Boeing 737
- Airbus A320
- RJ85
- Airbus A320
- Airbus A321
- Fokker 100

Comment: Ok, but how do I know the registration?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException That's the little code on the back of the aircraft fuselage :) (And the last two letters are displayed on the nosegear doors)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: Note also that you can determine the registration country of the aircraft from the code. If it starts with N it is USA, C is Canada, G is the UK, D is Germany, and so on.

Comment: And sometimes part of it is shown on the top of the vertical stabiliser as well, and/or on other places (e.g. KLM tends to put the last 2 letters over the windscreen rather than the nose gear bay doors).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer has good advice. I would add that a quick and easy way to make a guess at the manufacturer is to look at the ends of the wings. Notice how in the first picture the wings "bend up" at the end. This is [highly characteristic of Boeing 737s](http://www.b737.org.uk/winglets.htm).

By contrast, the "fence" style wing tip that you see in three of your photos is highly characteristic of Airbus.

See [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingtip_device) on the matter for more information about why wings have unusual tips.

Comment: Blended winglets are no longer unique to Boeing. I've started seeing Airbus's "Sharklets" in the wild.